# On aws ec2 the phpmy admin does not show edit delete options

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

---

### php my admin

I have installed the same version of phpmyadmin on my local and aws instance but on aws it is not showing edit delete option.

```
{
 img    text    
[BLOB - 4.6 KiB]    Tue Jun 16 12:37:42 IST 2015
[BLOB - 2.4 MiB]    Tue Jun 16 12:39:54 IST 2015

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add auto increment option in any field or an index

Comment: As the delete and update query is fired on edit and delete button with single where clause for which an unique id is must